# I'm allowed to rollback a post that has a pending suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, rollbacks

If you go into the revision history and select to rollback to a previous edit on a post which *also* has a suggested edit pending on it, it **works**. Even odder, the suggested edit remains active on the post for approximately 10 more seconds before it [gets rejected by... no one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/254259)?

Which way is it supposed to be? "Rejected by Community" or not allowed to rollback while there's a pending suggested edit?

**P.S.** I'm curious if making an edit through the revision history would also work. Clicking "edit" in the revision history actually brings up the edit screen, but I don't want to submit and accidentally waste *another* user's suggested edit.