# What can cause "This item is no longer reviewable"?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review

Upon random messing around on Stack Overflow I found [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1036842) which says:

> This item is no longer reviewable

What caused this?

My own assumptions are:

- The suggested edit did not get reviews in X hours thus "expired" and is now a zombie. Not likely though, as similar feature request I posted myself once was pretty much ignored.
- Looking in the [target post's revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13444808/revisions) I saw it got rolled back to a previous revision four minutes after the edit was suggested. Common sense says that when the post on which the edit was suggested is rolled back (and thus changed) that suggestion is now obsolete.

Deciding to check my second assumption, I searched Meta for more info just to find [this other suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/482655) that was victim of a Rollback ([Original post mentioning this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131157/im-allowed-to-rollback-a-post-that-has-a-pending-suggested-edit)) so it looks like that's still not the reason, unless it was a bug that got fixed in the meanwhile and instead of showing empty "rejected" it now shows the above message. (In such a case I would expect a dev to explain in the bug report, but there is nothing like that)

I checked couple more things:

1. If the target post get deleted, the suggested edit dies and results in a "Page Not Found" errror. (Happened to me just now by chance)
2. If I view suggested edit that I already reviewed before and is still active, it correctly shows:

   > You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed

Comment: Not sure, but I saw it a few times and I think the message just means others have already reviewed the item, so it's no more reviewable for you.

Comment: @Adinia nope. I reviewed thousands of suggested edits and that's the first time I see it. It always show either "Approved" or "Rejected" followed by whoever reviewed. If you already reviewed the item and it's  still in the active queue it shows "You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed"

Comment: Unrelated: two people voted to approve that?!

Comment: @Pop nope, just happened to me and it's a 404 Page Not found, even for 10K users. As for the two people approving you are correct, common example of robo approvers. (people reviewing just to get badges)

Comment: Hm, maybe the reason I couldn't find it was that it got fixed. And yes, I know about the "robo approvers," but that doesn't make them any less depressing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This suggested edit was made at 21:36:12 to [this revision of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13444808/2).

Then at 21:40:55, after getting 2 approvals, it was [rolled back to an earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13444808/3), thereby invalidating the suggested edit.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but why [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/482655) is different? On this one the rollback caused auto rejection in a weird way.

Comment: Just noticed you no longer working for SE... no goodbye party? ;)

Comment: I've just seen the "This item is no longer reviewable" for a case where only 1 review was made, and it was not made by a diamond mod. What's the reason in this case?