# How are 'edit suggestions rejected' counted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I noticed that the number of my 'edit suggestions rejected' has incremented and I would like to know why.

When I review my activity I can not find a suggested edit that was rejected recently. I can think of three things that may have counted as a rejected edit:

1. One of my approved edits was rolled back by the OP. I can't find that one now because it looks like the OP deleted his answer.
2. One of my suggested edits says 'This item is no longer reviewable.' I did notice that the OP made the same edits as I had suggested. Maybe we were making these changes simultaneously and his took precedence?
3. In the case of number one above, the suggestion was rejected by one reviewer and approved by three.

Which of these counts as a rejected suggestion?

Also, what is the meaning of 'This item is no longer reviewable.'? Is my assumption there correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why that item is no longer reviewable, but I would say that's a likely candidate for the second one of yours that got rejected.  It looks neater when posts have code items highlighted with the inline tags, but in all honesty, you should try to improve as much as you possible can in a post beyond that basic formatting, as in the past, people have abused that functionality to push through "junky" edits.

Most of your edits are reasonable.  The [other rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1117556) that you had was for modifying the code significantly, which as it seems you did it to match the OP's variable names, it wasn't as much of a cardinal sin as if you had modified it to suit your own purposes.  Still, reviewers tend to defend against such practices and will occasionally err on the side of caution (or perhaps be going too quickly, but that's another discussion).

2 rejections isn't a huge deal, so just learn from them, improve your technique, and get back in the saddle.

Comment: Yes, I realize that 2 rejections is not a big deal. And I do want to learn which is why I asked. I had already figured out why my first edit was rejected.

Comment: @toxalot [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156147/159165) confirms that your suspicions are true, I think.