# Who rejected this suggested edit to an orphan tag wiki?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, 10k-tools, rejected-edits, suggested-edit-stats

I was looking through the [Suggested Edits -> Rejected](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?tab=rejected&filter=All) section of the 10k tools on Retrocomputing and noticed something odd: a tag wiki was rejected, but no users made the rejection:

[image: Rejected Edit]

[Here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/82) is the review link.

How could have this edit been rejected by no one?  Was the edit pending when the tag wiki was orphaned (the tag was deleted)?  Is this intended behavior?  Are suggested edits to tag wikis automatically rejected when the tag is deleted?

Comment: Why would you want to keep around a pending suggested edit to a tag that has been deleted?

Comment: @Servy I wouldn't, but I would just like clarity around this behavior.  I would assume something like this would be rejected by the Community User with the message "tag was removed" or something like that.

Comment: Then ask that in the question; asking why there isn't a good message makes sense, but asking why we aren't keeping around edits to a deleted tag should be rather self evident.

Comment: @Servy I'm not asking "why we aren't keeping around edits to a deleted tags."  I'm asking "Who rejected this suggested edit to an orphan tag wiki?  Was this suggested edit delete by the system?"  You obviously didn't read my question.

Comment: @Servy: It really isn't self-evident at all; approved suggested edits are not removed in any way when the tag is deleted, and suggested edits to posts continue in the queue until they're handled.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You don't consider it self evident why you wouldn't want to continue reviewing edits of a tag that no longer exists?  Okay, so why would we want to continue reviewing edits of a tag that no longer exists?  Posts are only ever soft deleted; the post still is there to be edited; tags are hard deleted, when they're gone, they're gone.  There isn't even anything to apply the edit to.

Comment: @Servy I don't think we *want* to keep reviewing these edits, but the system's current behavior (including [keeping orphaned wiki revisions around](//ell.stackexchange.com/posts/78972/revisions)!) makes it reasonable to *expect* that behavior, and feature requests to remove rep etc from orphaned excerpts have been largely ignored.

Comment: @NathanTuggy how can a user submit an edit to the orphan wiki?  I just get a 404 error when I try.

Comment: @JAL: You can't, as far as I know. You *can* see past revisions if you have the URL, and past suggestions *do* contribute to current rep. For posts, a suggestion will remain in the queue until it's handled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nobody rejected it. It's not a rejected edit. It became unreviewable because the tag no longer existed while the edit was still pending, and thus there was nothing to connect it to anymore. There is a process that automatically kills off review tasks that are no longer needed. For suggested edits, this commonly occurs when the post (or in this case tag) gets deleted before the edit is fully reviewed.

To emphasize: it is **not** rejected and does not count as a rejected edit anywhere. It is simply an invalidated task.

Comment: So is this a bug with the 10k tools then?  From what you are saying it shoul say "invalidated" not "rejected."

Comment: @JAL Yes it should. Or just not show the edit there at all.

Comment: Thanks animuson, follow up bug report [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287929/242209).

Comment: You said that this edit was not rejected, but there is a rejection that appears on the user who suggested the edit's profile: http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/107/matt-lacey?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: That's another bug, the suggestion is listed as a rejected edit, and there is no title for the suggestion.  It just says "rejected edit on "

Comment: Another follow up bug report about the incorrect rejection, as well as the display issue on the user's profile: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287930/242209