# Invalidated Suggestions in the Suggested Edit Stats are incorrectly shown as Rejected

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, suggested-edit-stats

This is a follow up to [Who rejected this suggested edit to an orphan tag wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287927/242209).

Suggested Edits that are invalidated incorrectly show up as "Rejected."  The should be correctly labeled as "Invalidated" or not show up on the page at all.

[image: Rejected Edit]

[Review Link](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/82).