# An invalidated suggested edit on a user's profile appears as a rejection and is not displayed correctly

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This is a follow up to [Who rejected this suggested edit to an orphan tag wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287927/242209).

According to [this answer from animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287928/242209), invalidated edits should not count as rejected.  That does not appear to be the case, as [this user](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/107/matt-lacey?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) appears to have an a rejected edit from an invalidated edit.

[image: Stats]

The invalidated edit also does not appear properly on the user's profile:

[image: Rejected Edit]

The link is blank.  I'm not sure if this is specific for orphaned tag wikis or all suggested edits.

Another example:

[Little Snitch Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14678363) and [this user's activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1807667/ortomala-lokni?tab=activity).

Comment: Heh really weird that this never got updated anywhere. We explicitly made these not count so that users wouldn't get edit banned from invalidated edits. It makes no sense to continue showing them like this. Just confusing.

Comment: @animuson Do you think this is weird edge case with orphaned wikis?