# Text spacing off on when viewing a user's suggestion history in their profile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, mobile-safari

There should be more space between "on" and the tag wiki link:

> [image: Mobile Web]

- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Unrelated, but if you're wondering why the first two suggestions are blank, that's a different bug: [An invalidated suggested edit on a user's profile appears as a rejection and is not displayed correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287930/242209)