# Strange behavior of a suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

On MathOverflow Meta, I made a suggested edit to correct a typo in the tag excerpt to (product-discovery): https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/product-discovery/info.

However, this suggested edit:

- Is shown as "rejected edit" on my profile page: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/8250/martin-sleziak?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
- When I actually go to the suggested edit - https://meta.mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/1556 - I read: "Your suggested edit is pending review." (And I also see what was edited - as usually for suggested edits.) EDIT: Checking the edit a bit later I got: "This item is no longer reviewable." (Which is probably the expected behavior.)
- When I look at the same link while not logged on (in incognito mode), I get 404 not found.

It seems that this tag-info was created in some non-standard way, as explained in [Yaakov Ellis' comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346894/new-feedback-tag-product-discovery#comment1161747_346894). So it's quite likely that this is some edge case which only happens in unusual circumstances. Still, I thought it is worth reporting, in case this reveals some additional problems.

Comment: If it is showing you "Your suggested edit is pending review." then that is the bug. It should be showing "This item is no longer reviewable." which is what it displays for me. The wiki was since edited (6 hours ago) by the Community user to fix that mistake, and your suggestion is now invalid.

Comment: @animuson Interesting - now I also see "This item is no longer reviewable." I am pretty sure I saw "pending" when I decided to post a bug report here. (Now I went back to make a screenshot to see that it has change.) I think this would be rather difficult to reproduce. (So I will not object if this post is simply removed.)

Comment: Well if the edit was really rejected the expected behavior is that you can’t see it when logged out, to prevent rejected suggested edits from being effective for spam.

Comment: I think that the review invalidation is not done immediately, but by a timed script that hadn't yet executed at the time you posted this but has since run now. By the way, suggested edits you make that are later invalidated [show as "rejected" edits in your actions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253197/377214), but aren't actually considered "rejected" for determining your overall count or whether you should be banned from suggesting edits.

Comment: What most likely happened is that the dev route that Yaakov used didn't also auto-reject suggested edits as an edit conflict (as a post edit would normally do), so your edit remained pending. Then there's a scheduled task that checks for suggested edits to posts that have later been edited, and invalidates those reviews, just for that scenario (edit conflicts somehow not resulting in automatic rejections), and this one ran later.

Comment: @Laurel That mechanism is only supposed to kick in for suggested edits that trigger spam checks; some other rejected edits are in fact visible to logged-out users.

Comment: Well, it must be approved because the change has been made, however some other user could have made the change for you because it could be rejected.

Comment: Wait, did you log in? Because as I see it, the history shows a anonymous editor editing the excerpt of the tag. Community edited it which means that you could have made a rejected edit then logged out and made the edit again and that edit got approved. That way it means that the edit is rejected but both of the edits linked to the same page so the change was made. That's probably what happened.

Comment: @zixuan I don't think anonymous user can make a suggested edit to a tag-info on a per-site-meta. The [revision history](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/4522/revisions) shows edits by Community user. I have also [linked to the suggested edit](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/1556). My edit seems to be the [most recent suggested edit on that meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/1231352/recent-suggested-edits-on-tag-infos). Here are also [recent tag-info edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/969872/recent-tag-info-edits).